# number becomes string using NgModel binding

Tags: angular, typescript

I don't understand this behaviour with Typescript and Angular.

**my-component.html**

```
  <ion-select [(ngModel)]="creditAmount"
              (ngModelChange)="onChangeCreditAmount()">
    <ion-option value="25" selected="true">25€</ion-option>
    <ion-option value="50">50€</ion-option>
    <ion-option value="75">75€</ion-option>
    <ion-option value="100">100€</ion-option>
  </ion-select>
```

**my-component.ts**

```
  creditAmount: number;

  constructor() {
    this.creditAmount = 25;
    console.log(this.creditAmount);
  }
  onChangeCreditAmount() {
    console.log(this.creditAmount);
  }
```

In the constructor, creditAmount is a number. In the `onChangeCreditAmount` method, it became a string.

The only workaround I found is to use explicit cast: `Number(this.creditAmount)` but this seems hacky to me. Is there a better way ? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typescript only helps on compile time. The result will still be some JavaScript, which is not type safe. So you can assign `creditAmount` a number, a string, an array or whatever you like.

`NgModel` seems to work with strings only, so you have to parse it if you need a number. Sorry :-(

Comment: Thanks for this. You're right about Typescript. What about Angular itself? :)

Comment: Angular does not know about the type during runtime. It only reads the "value" from the selected option. And this value seems to be an string by default :-)

Answer (score 3):

Another way is to use the `+` operator the following way:

```
const str = '10';
const dig = +str;

console.log(str + ', ' + typeof str);
console.log(dig + ', ' + typeof dig);
```

Output:

```
10, string
10, number
```

Comment: Yes I saw it :) kind of the same explicit casting :)